# How to see which "using" is used in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

How can I see which `using` statements provides a class in Visual Studio 2013?

And how can I detect conflicts?

I have this kind of code

`foo.cs`:

```
namespace foo
{
    class XmlConverter 
    {
    }
}
```

`bar.cs`:

```
namespace bar
{
    class XmlConverter 
    {
    }
}
```

And I need to use both `foo` and `bar` namespaces (both have multiple classes).

EDIT: I know I can rename my classes (or use aliases) but how can I detect this issue(wrong class being used) ? Is it even possible ?

Comment: You need to provide the full namespaces name in order to avoid ambuigities.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, do you mean a fully qualified name , I already provided the full namespace ?

Comment: To see where a referenced item is defined, put your cursor on the type and press F12 - Go to definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use using aliases for this. Syntax looks like this: `using MyAlias = MyNamespace.A`.

See [Using alias directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and/or [How to: Use the Global Namespace Alias](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx)

In your case:

```
using FooConverter = foo;
using BarConverter = bar;

public ThirdPartyClass
{
     public void SomeMethod(FooConvert.XMLConverter fooConv, BarConverter.XMLConverter barConv)
     {
     }
}
```

of course that only makes sense when your actual namespace consists out of at least two parts or the name of the namespace is much longer and could be shortened without losing readability.

For example shorten `System.IO` to `SysIO` or `ThisIsMyNamespace` to `MyNamespace`. Else it's just more yping. With your example it makes more sense to just not have a `using` statement.

What is not possible is to somehow have the compiler 'detect' whether you are using foo's XMLConverter or bar's XMLConverter without putting some kind of classifier (be it alias or entire namespace) in front of the classname.

**To OP's update**: The compiler will let you know that something is wrong. The message is `Class1 is an ambiguous reference between Foo.Class1 and Bar.Class1`.

Comment: does the compiler always take the last using ?

Comment: @maaza no. If the compiler detects an ambiguous reference it will fail the compilation process. If it doesn't you don't have a reference to the assembly containing the second namespace/class. Or one of the two classes is `internal` or `protected` or `private` or something like that.

Comment: true, actually they are both internal.I guess I had bad luck with my setup

Comment: ah that could be a problem. Internal will only let you use a class from within the assembly it was defined in. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If there is a conflict then the C# will complain with an error.  In this case your code should use a fully qualified name as in `new foo.XmlConverter` or `new bar.XmlConverter`.

However this is bad practice.   If you can you should rename classes to `FooXmlConverter` and `BarXmlConverter`.

Comment: Or if it is fundamentally the same converter duplicated then refactor and move it to a common location... this is a common scenario in large projects.