# Could not evaluate expression - Linq Query just returning null

Tags: c#, linq

I'm really not sure what is happening here. I'm working on a few actions in my Web Api at the moment and one of them involves checking the presence of a contact in my database using an Identifier, then retrieving the contact if they are present.

So I have my expression:

```
var contact = context.Contacts.Where(x => x.UniqueId == Identifier).FirstOrDefault();

if (contact == null) { return "Identifier not recognised. Check correct type and Identifier"; }

//Goes on to perform tasks with contact information.
```

Then it goes on...But here is where it's behaving weirdly.

The original linq query is doing absolutely nothing. It isn't retrieving the contact for later use, and it also isn't even registering as null to trigger the return message.

In my debugging console the contact field is simply greyed out (visible, with a null value, but not able to be clicked on), and when I hit the refresh button in the value column it said

> Could not evaluate expression

What could be the reasons for this? My other API services which access the same db work absolutely fine, it is just this one line.

Possibly relevant fact

- There is a type conflict between two entities called 'contact' in two namespaces I'm utilising. I wouldn't have thought it would be important. Casting hasn't solved it. Just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: what is `Identifier` in your code? is it a local variable?

Comment: also, just fyi, you could refactor your code to `context.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UniqueId == Identifier)`. This is assuming `Identifier` is a local or global var of the same type as your `UniqueId`

Comment: It's likely that you're debugging in a context where the `contact` variable has gone "out of scope", so it no longer exists as such. Are you breaking exactly on the line that checks `if (contact == null)`?

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` does not always/does not have to return `null` when it finds nothing. It will always use the `default` value of that type. For complex types/classes that is `null`. But for an `int` it'd be 0. To be on the safe side, y ou should replace your `== null` check with `== default(Contact)`. Also if you've conflicting types it shouldn't compile at all. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199997/how-to-see-which-using-is-used-in-visual-studio)

Comment: @AlexPavlov Thanks, will do. Identifier is a local variable read from the POST method this sits inside. Debugging shows Identifier is as it should be.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Yes. Well I actually broke at the line above that and stepped through to that line. I've never seen a variable in debugger be greyed out saying null with a refresh button in the value field.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler Okay so it isn't a conflicting types issue. Noted about the default value, thanks for the comment.

Comment: what version of visual studio do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I made a couple of changes suggested in the comments above, and also defined the Contact explicitly and it now loads the Contact from the database fine. I'm really confused as to why as it's basically just refactoring, but the following is working:

```
namespace.Models.Contact contact = context.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UniqueId == Identifier);

//If Identifier isn't recognised return.
if (contact == default(namespace.Models.Contact)) 
{ 
     return "Identifier not recognised. Check correct type and Identifier"; 
}
```

The fact that this working code is no different functionally to the code posted in my question confuses me. I guess it must have been something my VS was doing instead.

Alex Pavlov in the comments points to https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Nov/21/Visual-Studio-2013-Could-not-evaluate-Expression-Debugger-Abnormality

This code is perfectly fine, I might have fixed it by restarting VS if it was simply that behaving strangely.

Comment: the reason why I asked about your visual studio version was because I stumbled on [this article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Nov/21/Visual-Studio-2013-Could-not-evaluate-Expression-Debugger-Abnormality). also, you did mention that your `Contact` class is ambiguous, and that does matter a lot. by specifying the namespace to which it belongs - you might have solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks! This is very interesting. I couldn't find an example which matched up. Solving the ambiguity was the only thing of note that I changed (other than restarting VS) so it's possible that was the solution. Strange one though!